# state monad haskell

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad

I want to write a function for calculating the average using the State Monad in haskell
this is the code I wrote as far

```
import Control.Monad.State
type MyState = (Double,Double)
media s (a,n)= ((a*n+s)/(n+1),n+1)

getAverage:: Double ->State MyState  s1-> Double
getAverage s c=get >>= \s0 -> let (x,s1) =media s s0
            in put s1 >> return x
```

I got this error when compile in GHCI, and I stuck there
can you help me to understand what is wrong, thank you in advance

Comment: You should paste what the error was.

Comment: What are you entering onto your command line to run this function `getAverage`?

Answer (score 6):

The code you provided gives this error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Double'
       against inferred type `m Double'
In the expression:
      get >>= \ s0 -> let (x, s1) = ... in put s1 >> return x
In the definition of `getAverage':
    getAverage s c = get >>= \ s0 -> let ... in put s1 >> return x
```

All this means is that the type resulting from the expression ("inferred") disagrees with the type signature ("expected"). In this case, `getAverage` operates in the `State` monad, so it's the type signature that's incorrect, as it can't evaluate to a non-monadic type.

Your code has other problems besides that, however, and won't compile even after fixing that particular issue. First a few stylistic issues to make it more readable:

- `getAverage` has an unused parameter, which is supposedly a value in the `State` monad, which doesn't really make sense anyway.
- Using the `do` notation is usually clearer than using `(>>=)` and lambdas, especially for something like `State`.
- The indentation of the second line is confusing, since the `in` goes with the `let` that's *inside* the lambda.

Making those changes we have this:

```
getAverage s = do
    s0 <- get
    let (x, s1) = media s s0
    put s1 
    return x
```

...which makes it easier to spot the next error: The second argument of `media` is a 2-tuple, and `s1` is just a single number, but you're trying to use both for the state value. Probably what you wanted was to set the state to `(x, s1)`, but return only `x`.

```
getAverage s = do
    s0 <- get
    let (x,s1) = media s s0
    put (x,s1)
    return x
```

This compiles just fine, but still needs some tidying:

- `media` needs to update the entire state value, so rather than `get`ting and `put`ting, just use the `modify` function.
- The return value is the first part of the state value, so just `fmap`ing `fst` over `get` is more straightforward.

So now we have something like this:

```
media :: Double -> MyState -> MyState
media s (a, n) = ((a * n + s) / (n + 1), n + 1)

getAverage:: Double -> State MyState Double
getAverage s = do
    modify (media s)
    fmap fst get
```

We can also note that `getAverage` is kind of doing two different things, and split it into separate functions:

```
updateAverage:: Double -> State MyState ()
updateAverage s = modify (media s)

currentAverage :: State MyState Double
currentAverage = fmap fst get

getAverage:: Double -> State MyState Double
getAverage s = updateAverage s >> currentAverage
```

**Edit**: And since I forgot about the minor detail of actually getting the results back out of the monad, replacing `updateAverage` with `getAverage` in Travis Brown's `getAverages` function will let it work on my code above.

Comment: @camccann - how do I run this from the command line?  I've loaded it into ghci, but am not sure what the call should be to getAverage

Comment: @SamHeather: You need to use `runState` or a similar function, e.g. `runState (getAverage 1) (2, 3)`. See the docs for the state monad here: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.0.1/docs/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html If you have questions beyond that, you'd probably have more luck posting it as a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Note: camccann's answer is better than mine, but mine takes a slightly different approach and gives an example of how to evaluate the state monad, so I'm leaving it here for reference.

---

We can start trying to figure out the problem by removing the type signature for `getAverage` and the argument (`c`) that doesn't appear in the function:

```
getAverage s=get >>= \s0 -> let (x,s1) =media s s0
            in put s1 >> return x
```

This still doesn't compile, because we're trying to `put` something that doesn't have the right type: `s1` is a `Double`, not a `MyState`. This is easily fixable:

```
getAverage s=get >>= \s0 -> let s1@(x,_) =media s s0
            in put s1 >> return x
```

We could also leave the `let` pattern unchanged and just say `put (x,s1)`: I'm doing it this way instead so that our `s1` has the same type as `s0`.

This compiles, so now we can fix the type signature. If we ask GHCi for the type, it returns the following:

```
getAverage :: (Fractional t, MonadState (t, t) m) => t -> m t
```

`Double` is an instance of `Fractional`, and `State MyState` is an instance of `MonadState (Double, Double)`, so we can use something very similar to your original type for `getAverage`:

```
getAverage :: Double -> State MyState Double
```

This function doesn't really "get" the average: it updates it after adding a new value, so let's rename it appropriately:

```
updateAverage :: Double -> State MyState Double
updateAverage s=get >>= \s0 -> let s1@(x,_) =media s s0
            in put s1 >> return x
```

Now we can define a `getAverages` function that takes a list of `Double`s, runs them through `updateAverage`, and returns a list of the intermediate averages at each step:

```
getAverages :: [Double] -> [Double]
getAverages ss = evalState (mapM updateAverage ss) (0, 0)
```

This does what we'd expect:

```
*Main> getAverages [1..10]
[1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5,3.0,3.5,4.0,4.5,5.0,5.5]
```

Note that to do anything useful with the `State` monad you'll always have to use `evalState` (or the closely related `runState` and `execState`).

Comment: An aside that I didn't think would help the questioner, but that you might enjoy: Notice how there's no flow control dependent on the state values? That's the tell-tale sign that this *doesn't need a monad*, and thus your version can be rewritten as `updateAverage s = modify (media s) *> (fst <$> get)`. Similarly, `mapM` can be generalized as `traverse`, which does the same thing for any `Applicative` through any `Traversable`.